# Why Java is not complaining about an ambiguous call?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

A service interface declares two methods which apparently do the same processing :

```
interface Service<T> {
    <R> R process(Function<? super T, ? extends R> function);
    T process(UnaryOperator<T> operator);
}
```

The service above is being called like below :

```
void process(Service<CharSequence> service) {
    service.process(sequence -> sequence.subSequence(0, 1));
}
```

Which one of the service methods are going to be called and why the compiler does not complain about an ambiguous call in this context?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Method resolution chooses the [*most specific* matching method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) when there are multiple possible matches. Since `UnaryOperator<T>` extends `Function<T,T>`, if that lambda matches it (and it does), it's more specific than `Function<T, T>` so the `UnaryOperator` overload will be used.

Comment: I totally forgot about the inheritance between a `UnaryOperator<T>` and `Function<T, T>`, thank you so much. Definitely, clears the ambiguity.

Comment: @HPH - To be fair, I had to look it up. :-)